# Get the value of a submit button to be a condition for alert message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, html-table

I want to get the value of the submit button to be called from a function that will be alert "function winningcombinations()" message.

This is My Script:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>




    <script>
    var nextTurn = 'X'
    function chose1() {          
       if (document.getElementById("Button1").click = true) {
           if (document.getElementById('Button1').value == "") {
               document.getElementById('Button1').value = nextTurn;
               document.getElementById('Button1').style.fontSize = "30px";
               document.getElementById('Button1').style.color = 'Blue';
               if (document.getElementById('Button1').value == "O") {
                   document.getElementById('Button1').style.color = 'Red'
               }
                   changeTurn();
               }
           }

       }
    function winningcombinations() {
           if (document.getElementById('Button1').value == "X" ) {
               alert("Congratulations X you won!!");
           }
       }
 </script>
```

This is one of the 9 buttons that I am working on:

```
                    <input id="Button1" style="width: 100px; text-align:center; height:      100px;" type="button" value="" onclick="chose1()"/></td>

 </tr>
        </table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. pass the value from onclick itself use `this.value`

```
<input id="Button1" style="width: 100px; text-align:center; height:100px;"type="button" value="X" onclick="chose1(this.value)"/></td>
```

in javascript

```
function chose1(bval1) {
  //write your code here
}
```